# Infinitesimals in an old Euler text (1778)

Tags: differential-geometry, math-history, infinitesimals

I'm working through the text *De curvis triangularibus* of Leonard Euler. In this paper he defines *orbiforms* as some kind of curves with constant height. He uses these curves to find *triangular curves* (figure 1) as the evolute of these orbiforms. In the part where he starts working with these evolutes he uses infinitesimals in a formula which I have never seen before, can someone deduce his reasoning?

#### Problem setting

Consider the *orbiform* in figure 6 *(drawn as a circle, but it doesn't need to be a circle)* In the problem setting both $Ff$ and $Mm$ are normal to the curve (in each endpoint). Through a parameterization of the orbiform he deduced
$$
FP = x = \frac{dS}{dp} \qquad   \qquad PM = y = \frac{pdS}{dp} - S
$$
for a certain function $S$. Through further calculations he ends up with:
$$
\sin \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \quad \& \quad \cos \phi = \frac{p}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} \qquad\Rightarrow \qquad d\phi =\frac{-dp}{1+p^2}
$$
He then writes:

> Quod si iam brevitatis gratia ponamus $FN=v$, notum est, centrum circuli, curvam in $M$ osculantis, fore in puncto $U$, ita ut sit
>   $$
>    NU = \frac{d v\sin \phi}{d \phi};
> $$

roughly translated as

> Let now for ease of use $FN=v$, it is known that the center of the osculationcircle in $M$ lies in the point $U$, then it is 
>   $$
>    NU = \frac{d v\sin \phi}{d \phi};
> $$

How did he deduce this last formula? In 1778 calculus was done using infinitesimals, and I guess $d v$ should be interpreted as a tiny increase of $v$, but how should I look at $d\phi$ and how did he derive this formula?

### Figures

[image: Triangular curves]
[image: Euler figure]

## EDIT 16 november

I've been looking trough other Euler and L'Hopital texts on curves, evolutes and involutes, but can't find any references. I did come up with an possible explanation though. Would it be reasonable that this was Euler's reasoning as well?

Consider the picture below, of a zoomed in version of fig 6. Let $NU$ progress by $d\phi$, then since two normals which are but an infinitesimal apart have the *same* radius of curvature, $U$ is still the same point of the osculating circle. Now apply the law of sines to $\triangle NUU'$.  Also note how $|NU'| = d v$. 
$$
\frac{NU'}{\sin d \phi} = \frac{NU}{\sin (\phi - d \phi)}
$$

If we replace $\sin d\phi \stackrel{?}{\approx} d\phi$ and $\sin(\phi-d \phi) \stackrel{?}{\approx}  \sin \phi$ it follows
$$
\frac{dv}{d \phi} = \frac{NU}{\sin \phi} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad NU = \frac{d v\sin \phi}{d \phi}
$$

Far fetched?

[image: Explanation]